# compare models in pymer4

Tags: python, r, lme4

Is there a way in `pymer4` (or similar python modules for linear mixed-effects regression models) to compare two different models?

In R, the command `anova` of the package `lme4` does this as follows:

```
model1 = lmer(DV ~ IV1 + (1|RV), data = data)
model2 = lmer(DV ~ IV1*IV2 + (1|RV), data = data)

anova(model1, model2)
```

The [API](http://eshinjolly.com/pymer4/api.html) page of `pymer4` does not seem to mention this. (I could do this in R, but I would rather do it in python, as I'll have to run this test through different groups through a `for` loop, for which python provides for flexibility.)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with rpy2 / rmagic.

Here is an example of a `for` loop where you are looping over different IVs, creating and fitting a new model, and comparing with the base model using `anova`.

```
# set base formula
base_formula = 'Weight ~ 1 + (1+Time|Pig)' # base model 
%R -i base_formula -i data m0 <- lmer(base_formula, data=data)

# loop over variables and compare models. 
for iv in ["Time", "Start"]:
  m_formula = f'Weight ~ {iv} + (1+Time|Pig)'
  %R -i m_formula -i data m1 <- lmer(m_formula, data=data); print(anova(m0, m1))
```

To run this example above, you'll need to import the `data` and set up your r environment which you can do with the code below or with the notebook associated with this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-run-linear-mixed-effects-models-in-python-jupyter-notebooks-4f8079c4b589) which I wrote to compare the different ways to run LMER in Python.

```
# Load dataset
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('dietox', 'geepack').data
#  Install Rbase and rpy2
# Install R and Rpy2
!apt-get install r-base
!pip install -q rpy2

# Install LMER packages (THIS TAKES ABOUT 3~5 minutes)
packnames = ('lme4', 'lmerTest', 'emmeans', "geepack")
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
utils = importr("utils")
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))

## Load modules. 
%R library(lme4); library(lmerTest)
```

Comment: this is such a great answer. With `rpy2`, can I have column names which include spaces and symbols in the `lmer` formula  ? Currently with statsmodel, it allows for variables with spaces and symbols by specifiying them like this `Q('column name with space & symbol > ')` Would I be able to do the same under `rpy2`